# How to create exe/jar file in netbeans that can be easily run on any other system

Tags: java, netbeans, jar

i hv created the .jar file by building my project in netbeans.

- The .jar file exist in "dist/myproject.jar". But when i move it to
  any other system will it find the paths specified for images etc in
  project?

  - As i am giving the paths like
    (C:/Users/Lucky/Documents/NetBeansProjects/CoverageAnalyzer/src/coverageanalyzer/icons/icon.png).
    OR When i write path just to approach root directory as
    (icons/icon.png), so then also?
- **Summary**: What is the actual way that i can write/copy my .jar file to
  any other system without spoiling the paths and program run correctly
  on any other system. Thanks in advance.help will be appriciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use one of the following approaches:

1. Use [relative paths](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/320542/how-to-get-the-path-of-a-running-jar-file) (relative to the executable file location) instead of absolute paths.
2. Use paths under a known absolute path (an installation folder, path from environment variable / configuration file / registry key, the user's directory ([`user.home`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/sysprop.html)) etc.)
3. Use resources embeded into your jar. See [`Class.getResource()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResource(java.lang.String)) and [`Class.getResourceAsStream()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResourceAsStream(java.lang.String))

**Note** that you should consider cross-platform (Windows/Linux/Mac) and resource hiding issues when selecting a suitable approach.

Comment: Thanks i used 3rd point that is embeding resource to my jar file.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to put the auxiliary files as resources into to jar. The program must then load them from the class path instead of the file system.

Have a look at `Class.getResourceAsStream`.